# Why parent object get printed instead of value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display a collections of object value but getting `#<PromoCode:0x007fa8123b2fd8>` this instead.

Here is my **controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_sources

private

def set_sources
  @pizzas ||= Pizza.all.order(:name)
  @promo_codes = PromoCode.all.order(:code)
end
```

Here is my **view.html.haml**

```
= f.input_field :pizza_id, as: :select, collection: @pizzas, class: 'form-control'
= f.input_field :promo_code_id, as: :select, collection: @promo_codes, class: 'form-control'
```

Here is my **schema.rb** for both models.

```
create_table "promo_codes", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "code", null: false
end

create_table "helpdesks", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
end
```

As you can see, I included `@pizzas` for comparison. But for pizza, Im getting the object name as I queried in the controller, but not for promo code code value.

[image: comparison]

I did `puts` for both `@pizzas` and `@promo_codes`, got the same result type, but not too sure why 1 is getting the value as wanted, but the other did not.

What should I google to point me into the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: Show your models for pizza and promo code. Do any have overriden `.to_s` or something?

Comment: No `.to_s` in both models. Models are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your controller promo code like below

```
  @@promo_codes = PromoCode.all.order(:code)
```

and rendering to view like below

```
collection: @promo_codes
```

**Update**

Try to the following

```
 = f.input :promo_code_id, collection: @promo_codes, label_method: :code, value_method: :serial, label: "Promo Code", include_blank: false, class: "form-control"
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a spelling mistake. I did put one @ only.

Comment: @IqlaasIsmail Updated answer try and see what happening

Comment: hey @fool-dev, please tell me what did you search ? :)

Comment: Ohh! I did not search anything but copy from my existing project and modified then put on my answer @IqlaasIsmail

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `to_s` in `PromoCode` model.

    `def to_s
      name #or another field which you want to show
    end`

Comment: I dont have `to_s` in my `Pizza` model, but why does it work ?

Comment: I'm no sure but maybe field `name` works in this role.